# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 504 Authenticate first (#5.5.0)

Tags: java, email

I am having issue sending mail via java.
the code do execute well from my local but show up the error in server

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 504 Authenticate first (#5.5.0)

please do guide me on how to proceed.

Snippet I am using

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
properties.setProperty("mail.user", userid);
properties.setProperty("mail.password", passwd);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: And how are you creating the Session?

Comment: using the above mentioned properties
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);